# How to keep rows based on certain string?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe like this:

```
bodies at low concentrations without dissociating them. {ECO:0000269|PubMed:27918561}.Nucleus {ECO:0000250}", 
"Nucleus {ECO:0000250}.Endoplasmic reticulum membrane {ECO:0000269|PubMed:24807418}; ", 
"Nucleus {ECO:0000269|PubMed:15897886}.", "Nucleus {ECO:0000305}."
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Try `subset(df, grepl("Nucleus", Subcellular.location..CC.))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Subcellular.location..CC.,"Nucleus"))
```